# Reduce Memory of Java Process

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-leaks

What is the best way for calling a method that's based on other method output in terms of memory usage?

For example:
First way:

```
Animal a = Farm.getAnimal(5);
item.setAnimal(a);
```

Second way:

```
item.setAnimal(Farm.getAnimal(5));
```

Moreover does saving the result of `item.setAnimal(...)` use Java memory?

Comment: No difference. The simple answer is that only a `new` will cause memory usage in java. But what does "saving the result" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are created on the heap and the object variable (Animal a) is actually referring to an object on the heap (There is no copy created when you assign this to a variable).

To answer your first question, both ways of setting the animal is same and does not create any additional memory usage.

But when you store the object into a variable, you should make sure that you are constraining the scope and hence not allowing for memory leak.

For your second question does item.setAnimal(..) use extra memory? -- the answer is obvious for the above reasons, it does not result in extra memory usage as the same object is being referred in the set method.